# Why Should I Adopt React Native in Old Projects?

Tags: mobile-application, react-native, react-native-ios

I've been digging deep in React Native for the past week to decide if I and the team should adopt it. And I gotta say it seems promising. I've also learned about its ability to integrate with existing native projects and its incremental adoption to change existing native projects.

My question is what are the cases/reasons that would make me wanna convert my completed old native projects (iOS/Android) into React Native?

Edit: Just to clarify, our team is currently building native apps only.

Comment: are they currently in nativescript?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon if u mean the team, nope we're building native.

Comment: so the app(s) are written in the native language (C++/C#/etc) not nativescript?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Swift/Java

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of app you are building. But you can always use bits of code from native or react native.   Since you all can code in native, anything you cannot find you could make a native component.

The advantages of React Native show up with code reuse between iOS and Android so that your team can iterate faster working together. Many big apps have achieved 80% or more code reuse.

You will find flexbox so easy to quickly create views to specs and to change quickly with styles. Plus they are all in code and that plays nice with git.

See edit below:
Now in saying this I have never used React Native inside a native project but to call actions and such you would need to expose functions to call from the JavaScript side. I don't know if a singleton is generally used or just an import of the controller functions or delegated you want to expose but it has to call back to the native application . It is easy to use a native component inside a React native application and I have done this so I am sure it can work the other way.

Edit: Out of curiosity I added some react native views to a test project and it works surprisingly well. No singleton needed Javascript maps the view tag and the exported functions.  Crazy. The concerns below still exist but I think if you are changing to change that is wrong but if you have UI changes you want to make then it could definitely benefit as your reuse can grow across your platforms.

Drawbacks I have seen- sometimes transition animations can be laggy if you are not using the native navigation methods. Using both native and React Native adds size to your app so you would need to keep an eye on that. Also start up time can hurt and so monitor that as well.

With all that said I have built a fair bit with React Native lately and it is, at times, beautiful and frustrating for a native developer.

Here is a great [article](https://engineering.instagram.com/react-native-at-instagram-dd828a9a90c7#.dnlt3w5ap) on Instagram and React Native.

Also AirBnb heavily uses RN. They may be completely RN now but I am not sure. They do drive a lot of the outside frameworks in RN for example the maps component in RN. They also just released Lottie and it is very cool. Here is an [article](http://devnacho.com/2016/03/20/how-airbnb-uses-react/) about AirBnb.

Comment: Using angular2 also results in large amounts of code use

Comment: @mast3rd3mon you're right about angular2 large code, laterally i switch from angular 1 to 2 while making hybrid but the out put isn't pleasant when it comes to size of code.

Comment: The size in the final project is not too bad at all. I have written a pretty neat tutorial on adding it to an existing project and will post it in the answer when I make it live. I am having someone proofread and test.